# Use identifier in PHP and how does it affect the logic

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, coding-style, identifier

Use identifier is used when we want to send some outer environment variables inside closures so I have a scenario.

```
$invoiceList = UserInvoice::where('user_id', $this->user->id)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($filters) {
                $query->where('invoice_number', 'LIKE', "%{$filters['invoiceNumber']}%")
                    ->when($filters['type'], function ($query) use ($filters) {
                        $query->whereIn('invoice_type', $filters['type']);
                    });
            });
```

In this Laravel eloquent query I have checked for filter['type'] when it is there then try to filter my invoice_type from filter[type]

But I am now confused here that what if I pass filters inside functions parameters like this

```
method 1 

->when($filters['type'], function ($query,$filters) use () {
                        $query->whereIn('invoice_type', $filters['type']);
                    });
```

Or

```
method 2 

->when($filters['type'], function () use ($query,$filters) {
                        $query->whereIn('invoice_type', $filters['type']);
                    });
```

What impact would it be if I opt these methods
I have also tried both and in method 1 it throws me an error that filters['type'] not available
and when I tried method 2 it works fine so please can any one explain how does it works I mean not theoretically but in practical language what basically happening there.
Also where it is defined that a closure function will accept how many numbers of arguments

Comment: The first code snippet: `function ($query) use ($filters)` is correct. That syntax isn't really optional. `function ($query, $filter)` won't work since the method (the `->where()`) that executes the function doesn't know what `$filters` is so it can't pass it as an argument. `function () use ($query, $filters)` might _seem_ as it's working, but that's more luck. That version will all use the same `$query` object everywhere, which can cause some serious side effects.

Comment: yes i have applied my first code in live environment but i was just curious and trying to do some here there so can you please explain what's wrong here and whats right in first code block and please pardon me if i am asking some illogical question

Answer (score 0):

The very last thought in your question is actually the key to your misunderstanding:

> where it is defined that a closure function will accept how many numbers of arguments

The answer is *wherever the function is eventually executed*.

In this case, you are passing the function to the `when` method; that method can decide when to execute it, and what parameters to pass when it does. We can [look at the source code directly](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Conditionable/Traits/Conditionable.php#L21) and see what happens:

```
public function when($value, callable $callback = null, callable $default = null)
{
    // some extra logic skipped as not relevant right now

    if ($value) {
        return $callback($this, $value) ?? $this;
    } elseif ($default) {
        return $default($this, $value) ?? $this;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

So, if `$value` is "truthy", $callback will be executed with exactly two parameters: the current object (`$this`) and the exact value provided (`$value`). In this case, that will be the query you're building, and the value of `$filters['type']`.

Think of it like handing over an envelope: you don't have any control of what the `when` method puts into the envelope, you just get to look at it once it's there.